# angularjs avoid scope.$watch from getting triggered during unit-testing

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am writing an angularjs app and in one of the controllers I have a watch expression on the method of a service :

```
$scope.$watch(CodeService.getCode, function(code){
 //Some code
});
```

In my unit-tests I mock the CodeService. How do I prevent the watch from getting triggered while I am testing other portions of the controller ?

Answer (score 1):

Its hard to tell the best way without more context, but a straightforward way would be to mock out `$scope.$watch`:

```
var watchSpy = spyOn($scope, '$watch').and.callFake(function(value, callback) {});
```

You can also test that it was called correctly:

```
expect(watchSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(CodeService.getCode, jasmine.any(Function))
```

If you just want to mock out this particular watch, you can stub `getCode` to always return the same value:

```
spyOn(CodeService, 'getCode').andReturn(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to use `spyOn` to make `CodeService.getCode` always return the same value. This may look something like this:

```
beforeEach(function() {
  ...
  spyOn(CodeService, 'getCode').andReturn(false);
  ...
});
```

This will fire once, but it should never fire again after that.

Comment: Thanks for replying. The problem is that even if the watch gets called once, the test would fail.